# Android: AppCompat v21 Menu item problems

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-menu

I'm busy with changing my existing app to material design, but i'm having trouble with the menu items inside the ActionBar.

First of all in some activities i'm using a searchview, But i have read that you need to use a custom prefix inside the searchview menu xml. So i did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item 
          android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search_light"
          android:title="Search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

But everytime I'm getting the error: 
"Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library"

if i change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseAction"` to `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` 
I'm not getting a searchview that take the whole lenght of the actionbar, just some strange square in the right corner where the items are placed. Here is my code of the onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchview, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView search = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    if(search != null)
    {   
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);

                try {
                    new LoadResultsTask().execute(URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(IndexerOverviewActivity.this, "Could not parse Query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String search) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I noticed aswell that all my actionbar menu items that has `android:showsAsAction="always"` are shown as `android:showsAsAction="never"` when i start my application on my device. So my first guess is it has everything to do with the prefix to use in the menu xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pffff, after just a single "clean" it works perfectly now...

It took me freaking 2 hours to fix this.